# Giving a lulav on condition to return, but in a chain where the last person keeps it

Tags: halacha, gezel-stealing, gifts, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, masechet-sukkah

The [Gemara in Sukkah on daf :מא](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp) relates a story of Rabban Gamliel, Rabbi Yehoshua, Rabbi Elazar ben Azaria, and Rabbi Akiva riding on a boat. The time came to shake lulav, but only Rabban Gamliel had a lulav.  Since it is required to shake one's own lulav on the first day of Sukkot, Rabban Gamilel gave his lulav as a gift to Rabbi Yehoshua. After being yotzei, Rabbi Yehoshua gave the lulav as a gift to Rabbi Elazar ben Azaria who gave it as a gift to Rabbi Akiva who subsequently returned it as a gift back to Rabban Gamliel.

The Gemara explains that the reason it was required to say in the story that Rabbi Akiva returned the lulav to Rabban Gamliel was to teach that a gift given on the condition that it will be re-gifted back to the original owner is considered a gift.

Further down on the page, we also learn that if someone gives a lulav as a gift on the condition that it will be returned, and the person does not return it, the receiver is not yotzei the mitzvah of lulav because he used a stolen lulav.

Tosfot explains that Rabban Gamliel actually gave the lulav on condition that it would be returned after *all* of the others on the boat had been yotzei.

So my question is as follows: What if Rabbi Akiva had decided to keep the lulav at the end and not return it to Rabban Gamliel? Would Rabbi Yehoshua and Rabbi Elazar ben Azaria be yotzei lulav? They did not personally steal the lulav, so I could definitely believe that if a person steals a gifted lulav, then the retroactiveness of the theft only goes back to when the person acquired the lulav. If others had it before him, since they didn't steal it, they could be yotzei. However, the gift was only given on the condition that it would be returned, which it was not, so perhaps the gift is considered to never have taken effect.

Answer (score 6):

[Shulchan Aruch (Orach Chaim 658:5)](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01043.html#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9FB%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%97B-B%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99B%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%91B%D7%91%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9DB%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91B%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F.B%D7%95%D7%91%D7%95B%D7%98%27B%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9D%3a-%D7%94.) rules explicitly that only if the last person returns the esrog is the first one (and all others) yotzei.

Interesting sidebar: The Biur Halacha is in doubt whether they were yotzei only if the last user returned the esrog on his own volition to the original owner or even if the original owner had to demand it back from the last user because it wasn't returned on its own.

Answer (score 1):

The condition would not have been fulfilled, so the gift would have been retroactively invalid, so no one (other than Rabban Gamliel) would have been allowed to use the lulav, so no one would have been *yotzei*.

Comment: Do you have any evidence of this?

Comment: @Daniel The first clause seems obvious, and the rest of the answer follows naturally.

Comment: It wasn't stolen until after they used it, so they didn't use a stolen lulav.

Comment: @Daniel But the condition was never fulfilled, right? So it's _retroactively_ stolen.

Comment: That's why I want to see evidence. That _could_ be the answer, but I think there is definitely a plausible hava aminah that if a person steals a gifted lulav, then the retroactiveness of the theft only goes back to when the person acquired the lulav. If others had it before him, since they didn't steal it, they could be yotzei.

Comment: @Daniel But it's a _matanah al menas lehachazir_, on condition to **return** the lulav. If they didn't return it, there was never a _matanah_.

Comment: I would say that is possibly incorrect. The Gemara explicitly states that the reason that the person is not yotzei is because he used a stolen lulav. Not because the gift wasn't chal. _Perhaps_ the gift wasn't chal, but I don't think it's as clear as you claim. I think it is completely reasonable to say that the gift _was_ chal, but that it was stolen later. If that's the case, then perhaps only people who used it after it was stolen are not yotzei.

Comment: In other words, after a matanah al menat lehachzir, it is clear that the lulav is the property of the receiver. Otherwise, he would not be able to be yotzei lulav. If he does not return it, then it is as if he stole it at the time that he received it. But if there is a chain of people who the original giver had in mind to give it to before he received it back again, then the lulav passed into and out of a few different people's reshut without being stolen. It was only stolen once those people had been yotzei and the lulav had already exited their reshut

Comment: @Daniel I don't think the recipient acquires the lulav at all unless he fulfills the condition by returning the lulav. In this case, he never returned it, so why would it matter if he gave it to five other people in the meantime?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15047/discussion-between-daniel-and-ypnypn).